# Where Do I Vote to Reopen a Question?: I Don't See Where to Do This

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen

The following question has been closed:

[How can I apply Six Sigma in a software development environment?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/146909/how-can-i-apply-six-sigma-in-a-software-development-environment)

I feel it is a very valid question and have some sub-questions for it.

I can't find where to navigate to re-open the question.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You need 3000 reputation on the main site to cast close and open votes on questions, so the link below the question to cast the vote will not show up. In the mean time, you can ask about it on Meta or flag it for moderator review.

This particular question won't likely be reopened - it's [overly broad](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490). There are entire books about applying Six Sigma to software engineering ([1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1420044265), [2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071700625)), and some freely available resources linked to in the original question.

Also, there isn't a concept of a "sub-question" on Stack Exchange. If you have questions that you think are [on-topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and are written to avoid the things that [shouldn't be asked](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and you [formulate it well](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), your question shouldn't be closed. Feel free to ask a new question - specific, well-written, and well-scoped questions about applying Six Sigma to software engineering is within the scope of this site. If you aren't sure, feel free to pop into chat or ask a question on Meta - someone will be able to help make sure your question is good for the site, point you to a better site, or point you to some resources to get you moving in the right direction so that if you have further questions, they are more appropriate for the site.